# Integral of (harmonic/fundamental)

Tags: integration

I would just like to ask whether these equations would evaluate to 0:

$\int \frac {\sin nx}{\sin x} $

$\int \frac{\cos nx}{\cos x}$

and if not, what conditions are necessary. Btw, the limits would be one period of the fundamental. n would be any positive integer greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

Not for all $n$. Let $n=1$

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{\sin(x)}\mathbb{d}x=2\pi\neq 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Doing some calculations via Desmos, the first integral is $0$ whenever $n$ is even and $2\pi$ whenever $n$ is odd.

The second one plays hard to get. It equals $2\pi$ whenever $n$ is one more than a multiple of 4 and $-2\pi$ when $n$ is one less than a multiple of four. When $n$ is odd the integral is properly undefined. However, an improper integral cutting out the infinite discontinuities (where $\cos(x)=0$ at $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$) shows:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^{\pi/2-h}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos(x)}dx+\int_{\pi/2+h}^{3\pi/2-h}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos(x)}dx+\int_{3\pi/2+h}^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(nx)}{\cos(x)}dx=0$.